# How to match Google translate result with input string

Tags: json, coldfusion, google-translate, google-translation-api

I want to convert a N number US english to some other languages. I've a US string as "JSON" format like below,

```
"AdminLocales": {
    "-locale": "en_US",
    "global": {
      "search": "Search",
      "noOrdersFound": "No Orders Found",
      "prevPage": "Prev Page",
      "nextPage": "Next Page"
    },
     "languageList": {
      "1": {
        "type": "Student",
        "area": "Kovilpatti"
      },
      "2": {
        "type": "Employee",
        "area": "Tuticorin"
      },
    }
}
```

I want convert almost 3000 string. So I've deserializeJSON my input and loop over the data. Which mean I called the google translation API for each string so my API call will be 3000 times.

So I'm facing request time out issue while call that much time in that API. Like below code

```
<cfset myKey = 'abcd'>
<cfhttp url="https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=#myKey#" method="post" charset="utf-8"  result="getTokens">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
      <cfhttpparam type="body" name="data" value="{
 'q': 'Welcome',
 'target': 'hi'
}"> 
</cfhttp>
```

And I found that as we can pass N number of source string input at the same time So I passed it as below

```
<cfhttpparam type="body" name="data" value="{
     'q': 'Welcome',
     'q': 'Good Morning',
     'q': 'Good Evening',
     'q':'Welcome to all',
     'q': 'Good night',
     'target': 'hi'
    }">
```

And I got the result as the out is same order of input which is I'm passed,

```
" { "data": { "translations": [ { "translatedText": "स्वागत हे", "detectedSourceLanguage": "en" }, { "translatedText": "शुभ प्रभात", "detectedSourceLanguage": "en" }, { "translatedText": "सुसंध्या", "detectedSourceLanguage": "en" }, { "translatedText": "सभी का स्वागत हैं", "detectedSourceLanguage": "en" }, { "translatedText": "शुभ रात्रि", "detectedSourceLanguage": "en" } ] } } "
```

This is fine for normal testing.

Now come back to my input, How I can pass the all input at the same time and matched with the result of https call. Becuase I'm not having any sequence order of inputs. I've structure of structure and it's child structure etc... From my input if I pass as "Search,Prev Page,Next Page,Studen,Kovilpatti etc" ( Source string ) it's return the same order. Here How I can match that particular result is for particular source string.

Is Google would expect that you'd pass in a key to identify the correct return ?

Comment: Do you have control over the source string?

Comment: Yes. I've an control. @Ageax

Comment: If you're building the JSON string, you can use an "ordered" structure (new in CF2016) which maintains sequence in which items are added. Otherwise, you may have to keep track of the order manually, with an array. Then match it up with the array google returns. **Edit** AFAIK, there's no support for ordered structures when you use structure literal syntax, not in any version. Very surprising given the prevalence of JSON ....

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solutions for my logic. Here I've explain about how to resolve this kind of scenario. We can achieve this by passing some delimiters. Here I've used - ( Hyphen )as my delimiters.

```
<cfset myStr = {'Name':'Kannan','State':'Tamilnadu','Country':'India','Position':'Projects Lead','Description':'Test translate API call'}>
```

This above is my original structure. I've convert this structure key values with hyphen delimeters like below,

```
<cfset convertString = ''>
<cfloop index='keys' list="#keyList#">
    <cfset convertString = listAppend(convertString,structFind(myStr,keys),'-')>
</cfloop>
```

Now my string looks like **Tamilnadu-Kannan-Test translate API call-India-Projects Lead**

I can pass the above string in single http call by calling below API,

```
<cfhttp url="https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=myApiKey132" method="post" charset="utf-8"  result="returnData">
     <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
     <cfhttpparam type="body" name="data" value="{
'q': '#convertString#',
'target': 'hi'
}"> 
 </cfhttp>
```

The API call return data like below image,
[image]

So my converted string should have my passed delimeter like **तमिलनाडु-कन्नन-टेस्ट अनुवाद एपीआई कॉल-इंडिया-प्रोजेक्ट्स लीड**

Now I can loop over the result based on my delimeter - ( Hyphen ) and matched my structure key like below code.

```
<cfset convertStr = {}>
<cfset apiResult = deserializeJSON(returnData.filecontent)>

<cfset a = 1>
<cfloop index="result" list="#apiResult.data.translations[1].translatedText#" delimiters="-">
    <cfset structInsert(convertStr,listgetat(keyList,a),result)>
    <cfset a = a+1>
</cfloop>
```

Finally I got my expected result.

**Original Structure**

[image]

**After the translation:**

```
<cfdump var="#convertStr#" label="Google Translate Structure" />
```

[image]

Thank you for all attention on these.